# Will .NET Core applications work on a server with only .NET Core installed?

Tags: linux, nginx, .net-core

I am planning to buy a Linux server. I have some APIs written in .NET Core (C#) and so I will be installing only .NET Core on my sever.

When I deploy my APIs, will they work with only .NET Core or will there be some dependencies on .NET Framework, too?

Comment: I suppose by APIs you mean ASP.NET Core services? First, only .NET Core runs on Linux. Second, only .NET Core will be developed going forward. New C# features, the new ASP.NET Core v3 will only target .NET Core, because they *require* new runtime features .NET Core has no dependencies on the Full framework, it wouldn't be cross-platform if it did.

Comment: All you need to know .net framework will not work on linux.

Comment: For example, the [nullable references in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-types) that everyone is excited about require support from the runtime.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - re: Framework development - that's not what [Microsoft have said](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/update-on-net-core-3-0-and-net-framework-4-8/): "Both .NET Framework and .NET Core will move forward, and both will be fully supported"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever read this again, in light of C# 8 and ASP.NET Core. People are complaining about that article.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever [Check this](https://twitter.com/pkanavos/status/1097919983869485058). Until you posted that link I thought Morten Nielsen was just grumbling, but it turns out he's right. Check the original tweet by [Matt Warren](https://twitter.com/matthewwarren/status/1097825993329426432) too `Interesting, I never really thought about this. If the .NET Framework (run-time) isn't updated to support 'default interface methods' it won't be able to *fully* implement C# 8.0!`

Answer (score 0):

If you will be running the .Net core via kestrel server, you won't be having any dependency on .Net framework for execution.

More details on https://stackify.com/what-is-kestrel-web-server/

Comment: You won't have any dependencies to the Full framework anyway

Answer (score 0):

Net Core is “bundled” so it runs isolated anyway.. Go with the new Net Core and you’ll be fine. It has no dependencies in Net Framework

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's up to the developer to embed the .net core runtime in their application. If you don't do this, you still have to install the .net core runtime on the target machine for it to run. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2 this page contains binaries for the .net core runtime for Linux. Why would that be a thing if you can only embed the runtime?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I should have been more specific. “Bundled” is an option.. But, you can just install the runtime on Linux too if you wanted.